# Maximum port number used for bind() fun call

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket

What is the maximum number that can be used for sin.sin_port, My application connect multiple times with different sin.sin_port number,

Is there any upper limit for the sin.sin_port number

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;   
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(22345);

bind(listensock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sinlen))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A port number is an unsigned 16-bit quantity, whose maximum value is therefore 65535. The zero is reserved to mean 'any port'.

But the code you have shown doesn't appear to connect at all: given the variable name, it listens, and there is no therefore apparent reason for it to use more than one port.